# 'beforeunload' event only fires in firefox when I click on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I open a new window using window.open()

And then I am trying to run some script(an ajax call) when user closes the opened window.

The open works fine,but the code doesn't work as expected in FF when I try to close the window

Here is my code

```
<?php

echo '<div id="iframecontainer"><iframe name="meeting-iframe" frameborder="0" style="width:80%;height:80%" src="' . $link . '"></iframe></div>';


?>
<script>
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function() {


    // Variables from php
    var event_id = '<?php echo $event_id; ?>';
    var user_id = '<?php echo $current_user->uid; ?>';
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Run function before window is closed,doesn't work as expected in FF
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {

      var e = e || window.event;
      var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave the meeting?';


      if(e) {
        e.returnValue = message;
      }


     // Post to get meeting info
      $.post('/easymeet/getInfo/' + event_id).done(function(meetResponse) {
        //ajax callback ,I have hidden the code here as I don't think its relevent to the question

      });
    });

  });
}(jQuery))
```

I am loading an iframe inside my window and the page the iframe is fetching is all flash(just to point out).

I am testing in IE,chrome and Firefox
Whats happening here is beforeunload is triggered and works well in IE and Chrome.

But in Firefox I **manually** have to **click** on the HTML or do some interaction. If I try to close the window without doing anything, the 'beforeunload' event doesn't seem to fire at all.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @IonicăBizău did you find any solution to this? im scratching my hair

Comment: @slier No, it's simply the way how Firefox works (unless you change the `about:config`––as mentioned below––, which you are not interested to do so, probably). I'm afraid there's no way to force that.

Comment: @IonicăBizău yep, i guess so ..thx!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has some configurations that you can find writing "about:config" in the navigation toolbar. There you'll find some flags, including **dom.require_user_interaction_for_beforeunload** that makes 'beforeunload' event fires only when you click on the page. But you can't modify this configuration through code; You have to do this manually in Firefox.

PS: sorry for my english.